# GPUImage still camera ..white screen

Tags: ios, gpuimage

i have an iPad 2,where i am testing this code in my viewDidLoad iam calling this

```
-(void)stillCameraStart{
GPUImageStillCamera *stillCam=[[GPUImageStillCamera alloc]init];
GPUImageView *filterView = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0,768, 1024)];
GPUImageGammaFilter *filter = [[GPUImageGammaFilter alloc] init];

[stillCam addTarget: filter];
[filter addTarget: filterView];
[stillCam startCameraCapture];
}
```

but all that i get is white screen.am i doing something wrong?i am expecting a camera to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed this statement ??

```
[self.view addSubview:filterView];
```

Comment: ohh yeah..such a small thing :P